# Interactively changing colorbar ticks to logarithmic format

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am designing a `Matplotlib` 2D map where I want to interactively change between a normal and logarithmic scaling of the thicklabels of the colorbar (not change the colormesh). So I want a RadioButton that can change the thicklabels from:

[image: Normal scale]

to

[image: Logarithmic scale]

I have designed a `RadioButton` to do so

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

def scalefunc(label):
    if label == 'Normal':
        cb.set_format(None)
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    elif label == 'Log':
        cb.set_format(LogFormatter(10, labelOnlyBase=False))
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

Xi = np.random.random((100, 100))
Yi = np.random.random((100, 100))
Zi = np.random.random((100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.23, bottom=0.25)

pcm = ax.pcolormesh(Xi,Yi,Zi, cmap = 'gist_gray')
cb = plt.colorbar(pcm, extend='max', format = None, pad = 0.04)

buttonax3 = plt.axes([0.04375, 0.7775, 0.075, 0.075])
scale_button = RadioButtons(buttonax3, ('Normal', 'Log'), activecolor='steelblue')
scale_button.on_clicked(scalefunc)

plt.show()
```

But this made me realise that `colorbar` has no `set_format` attribute as I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'Colorbar' object has no attribute 'set_format'
```

This puzzles me because I can set the ticklabels of the colorbar directly to logarithmic using the `format` option:

```
pcm = ax.pcolormesh(Xi,Yi,Zi, cmap = 'gist_gray')
cb = plt.colorbar(pcm, extend='max', format = 
                  LogFormatter(10, labelOnlyBase=False), pad = 0.04)
```

So how can do I need to design the `scalefunc` function to be able to switch between the two thick labels on the colorbar?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish here. Do you want to change the formatting of the ticklabels? Do you want to change the colorscale of the colorbar (and the colormesh)? In any case, a [mcve] will help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want to change the formatting of the thicklabels and not the colorscaling itself.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: I'm happy to look into the issue if a [mcve] is available. Otherwise someone else might want to look at it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think I have given all the information right now without adding the unnecessary data I use to construct the colormesh. Is this according to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to "bump" them. If you want to get help, it would be better to create an MCVE as has already been suggested. Currently your code is certainly Minimal, but neither Complete nor Verifiable.

Comment: I have added a minimal example that should be complete and verifiable. Hopefully someone can help me now.